# Would some of the solutions to this function be considered hypercomplex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions, hypercomplex-numbers

Consider the following function;

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$$

If this function were to be plotted onto a 3-dimensional co-ordinate space, then the x and y axes would be orthogonal to each other.

What happens to this function however, when the values for both x and y are less than zero? For example, if we have;

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{-1} + \sqrt{-1}$$

does this become;

$$f(x,y) = i + j$$

and if so, are i and j also considered orthogonal to each other, in the same way that the x and y axes are?

Furthermore, what if the original function is now altered so as to be defined as follows;

$$f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} + \sqrt{z}$$

Similarly, what happens to this function if x, y, and z are less than zero. For example, if we have;

$$f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{-1} + \sqrt{-1} + \sqrt{-1}$$

does this become;

$$f(x,y,z) = i + j + k$$

where i, j, and k in this case are orthogonal to each other? Is what we have here, an instance of a hypercomplex number (with a real component of zero), and if it had a non-zero real component tacked onto it, would this be an example of Hamilton's quaternions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No(Edit: No is not completely correct. It depends should be the answer) . The solution would simply be expanded to include complex numbers. In your example this wouldnt be $ i + j $ but $2i$. Another axis in the 4th dimension would be necessary to present the solution $2i$.

Edit: You could however define that the function maps to the quaternions in which case this would be one of the infinitely many possible solutions, so it would be correct the way hou wrote it. But so would 2i, i+k, j+k,...

Comment: Ahh, yes. That makes sense now. So how would the j and k components in a quaternion come about then, or is it not as straight forward as I might think? The j and k components are imaginary as well, aren't they? I'm guessing this is why quaternions are classified as hypercomplex numbers?

Comment: The quaternions are just defined to represent rotation in 3D space. Forget about the idea of imaginary numbers in this case. The definitiin i*j*k=-1 means that if you rotate the number one by i, j and finally k you land on - 1. Likewise if you rotate by k and by k again you land on - 1.The same is true for j and i. Your example is simply a function that maps from the 2Dreal numbers to 2D complex numbers, not 4D quaternions.

Comment: You could however define that your function maps to quaternions and not just 2D complex numbers. In this case you get infinitely many solution for the square root of - 1 and could indeed write the solution the way you wrote it. But this would be just one of the infinitely many possible solutions.

Comment: I understand how both of the functions, i.e. f(x,y) and f(x,y,z) can map to 2d and 3d numbers respectively, but how do I make these two functions map to quaternions? Also, what would the solution to the latter of these two functions look like, if it were to be represented in vector notation when x=y=z=-1? Would it be f(x,y,z) = ii + ji + ki, where the leading i, j, and k characters represent the 3-dimensional unit vectors, and the three trailing i characters represent the imaginary number sqrt(-1)? Furthermore, was it Oliver Heaviside and others who introduced vector notation from quaternions?

Comment: You do not have to "do" anything other than declare that this function maps to the quaternion space. Let's take three examples: 1) If you decide the function maps to the real numbers, then $sqrt(-1)$ does not exist in the real number space. 2) If you decide the function maps to the complex plane then $sqrt(-1)$ = $i$ and for your specific function you get $sqrt(-1)$ + $sqrt(-1)$ = $i$+$i$. 3) If you decide that the functions output can also include the quaternion space, then your function's output for x=-1,y=-y,z=-y can have multiple solutions. It can be $3i$, $i+j$, $i+k$,... In other words..

Comment: in the quaternion space, the solution to $sqrt(-1)$ has infinitely many solutions that all line on the unit sphere. For more detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Square_roots_of_%E2%88%921